# Column label as variable name when using prcomp

Tags: r, label, spss, prcomp

I have a data frame* with column labels. How can I use, or show, those column *labels* instead of column *names* when, for instance, using `prcomp`? (The function `get_label` below, is from the package `sjlabelled`.)

```
> get_label(spss.wvs) %>% head(2)
           wvs_e069_01                wvs_e069_02 
"Confidence: churches" "Confidence: armed forces"
```

What I get (through `prcomp`) is:

```
> pca.wvs$rotation %>% head(2)
                PC1        PC2
wvs_e069_01 -0.08513771 0.45688379 
wvs_e069_02 -0.23062304 0.05508813
```

*What I want* is:

```
> pca.wvs$rotation %>% head(2)
                PC1        PC2
"Confidence: churches" -0.08513771 0.45688379 
"Confidence: armed forces" -0.23062304 0.05508813
```

* The dataset is imported from [spss](/questions/tagged/spss) ([dropbox link to .sav](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfpb563io5bkpe7/qog_std.sav?dl=0)) through package `haven` in the following fashion:

```
library(haven)
haven.imp <- read_spss("qog_std.sav")
library(dplyr)
spss.wvs <- haven.imp %>% dplyr:: select(starts_with("wvs_e069_0"), starts_with("wvs_e069_1"), grep("wvs_e069_20", names(haven.imp)))
```

(I'm sure there are more effective ways of getting "everything between wvs_e0690_00 and wvs_e0690_20", but at least this does the trick. Pointers are appreciated though. As you can tell, I am a beginner at [r](/questions/tagged/r).)

Output of `str(spss.wvs[1])` is:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   193 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ wvs_e069_01: num  NA NA NA 3.17 NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Confidence: churches"
  ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
```

Comment: Where does function `label` come from? And can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(spss.wvs)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(spss.wvs, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for taking the time to comment! Posted link to dataset. Also changed from (Hmisc) function `label` to (sjlabelled) `get_label`. I'd add the output of `dput(head...)`, but I'm not sure it would add anything, since, for instance, labels aren't shown in that output?

Comment: Added output of `str(...)` instead of `dput(...)`; seemed it might be more helpful, as it contains the attribute label, which is what I'd like to work with, so to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I can do:

```
> library(sjlabelled)
> rownames(spss.wvs$rotation) <- get_label(wvs)
```

Which gives me

```
> spss.wvs$rotation %>% head(2)
                                 PC1        PC2
Confidence: churches     -0.08513771 0.45688379
Confidence: armed forces -0.23062304 0.05508813
```